# Poller to continue after exception

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to address the following constraints to integrate a system that uses its Database as queue (EaiAckNackOut object in my example):

1. poll from a MessageSource several Messages at a time not to criple the DB.
2. One record cannot be polled more than once. As far as I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301870/prevent-a-message-to-be-polled-more-than-once-using-spring-integration), it means that the same thread must handle all the messages (which is fine, handling is very light) so that the next polling is blocked until the current one finishes.
3. Each Message must be handled in its own transaction, in isolation from the other messages.
4. There must be `processBeforeCommit()` / `processAfterRollback()` using `TransactionSynchronizationProcessor` (or equivalent).

The solution I have in mind is to execute sequentially in a single thread:

```
Begin transaction
handle message1
Execute processBeforeCommit()
Commit transaction
Execute processAfterCommit()
Begin transaction
handle message2 (throws exception)
Rollback transaction
Execute processAfterRollback()
Begin transaction
handle message3
...
```

I am getting very close using "smart" `MessageSource` that returns one message at a time, combined with a `Poller` configured with `.maxMessagesPerPoll(10)`

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExampleMessageSource implements MessageSource<EaiAckNackOut> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private List<EaiAckNackOut> eaiObjects;
    private final QEaiAckNackOut eaiObject = new QEaiAckNackOut("eaiObject");

    @Override
    public Message<EaiAckNackOut> receive() {
        if (eaiObjects == null || eaiObjects.isEmpty()) {
            eaiObjects = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager)
                    .selectFrom(eaiObject)
                    .where(eaiObject.id.in(1,2,3)
                    .orderBy(eaiObject.id.asc())
                    .fetch();
        }

        if (eaiObjects.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return new GenericMessage<>(eaiObjects.remove(0));
    }

    @Override
    public IntegrationPatternType getIntegrationPatternType() {
        return IntegrationPatternType.pollable_channel;
    }
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EaiTransactionSynchronizationProcessor implements TransactionSynchronizationProcessor {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void processBeforeCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
        EaiObject eaiObject = (EaiObject) holder.getMessage().getPayload();
        eaiObject.setEaiStatus(EaiObject.EAI_STATUS_PROCESSED);
        eaiObject.setEaiProcessed(LocalDateTime.now());
        log.info("This is a message before commit of {}", eaiObject.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void processAfterCommit(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
        EaiObject eaiObject = (EaiObject) holder.getMessage().getPayload();
        log.info("This is a message after commit of {}", eaiObject.getId());
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void processAfterRollback(IntegrationResourceHolder holder) {
        EaiObject eaiObject = (EaiObject) holder.getMessage().getPayload();
        eaiObject.setEaiStatus(EaiObject.EAI_STATUS_ERROR);
        eaiObject.setEaiProcessed(LocalDateTime.now());
        entityManager.merge(eaiObject);
        log.info("This is a message after rollback of {}", eaiObject.getId());
    }
}
```

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow splitExample() {
    PollerSpec pollerSpec = Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
            .transactional()
            .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory);

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(exampleMessageSource, c -> c.poller(pollerSpec).autoStartup(true))
            .handle(getHandler())
            .get();
}

private GenericHandler<EaiAckNackOut> getHandler() {

    return new GenericHandler<EaiAckNackOut>() {
        @Override
        public Object handle(EaiAckNackOut payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
            log.info("Handling eaiInsertKey={}", payload.getId());
            if (payload.getId().equals(2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("bad move");
            }
            return payload;
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is that the poller stops after the exception on Message 2 (`processAfterRollback()` is executed correctly), and Message 3 is not handled.
Is there a way to make the poller continue after the exception ? Or should I take a completely different approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's an existing logic:

```
                while (this.initialized && (this.maxMessagesPerPoll <= 0 || count < this.maxMessagesPerPoll)) {
                    if (this.maxMessagesPerPoll == 0) {
                        logger.info("Polling disabled while 'maxMessagesPerPoll == 0'");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (pollForMessage() == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
```

So, we call `pollForMessage()` in a loop until it returns `null` or we have reached `maxMessagesPerPoll` limit.

If an exception is thrown, then we break the current polling cycle and go to the idle period until the next one starts its task.

Not sure what is wrong with that as long as the data in DB is consistently updated on every successful transaction. This way a new polling cycle would really pick up those records dropped with the previous task with the mentioned exception thrown.

If you still insist to finish the current polling cycle ignoring those error in between, then you need to consider to implement custom AOP `MethodInterceptor` to intercept an exception from the `invocation.proceed()` and swallow it. This advice must be configured higher in a chain with the mentioned transaction interceptor.

In other words you must use an `advice(Advice... advice)` method to supply two advices an don't use that `transactional()`. But again: I'd like to understand what is the problem to come back to those records in the next polling cycle?